# Count check before Linq Single() call

Tags: c#, linq, exception

Should I check `Count` before Linq Single() call if I expect only one element?

```
if (objects.Count != 1)
{
    throw new
        InvalidOperationException(
            "%Collection% should contain one %element%, but now it's: "
                 + objects.Count);
        }

return objects.Single();
```

`Single` implements the same check and throwing. But its message is less specific.

P.S. in my case wrong count is handled just writing log message like

```
_log.Error("Error during %operation%", ex);
task.Complete(TaskResult.Fail);
```

Comment: For clarity, are you trying to alleviate the potential to avoid the error if Single grabs more than one element or executing on a null object?

Comment: @Greg I expects that collection should contain only one element. All other (0 or more than 1) is error.

Comment: @SerG Does the count matter?  I could see an argument that you may want to log the contents of the collection when the error occurs, but I can't really see how the scalar count value helps much.

Comment: Yes, the count matters. You can't see because it's minimalized fragment. You can assume that items of collection are logged.

Comment: I almost always check the count myself because just like you've said, the message the `Single` methods outputs doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, go for it. Adding more detail to error messages is helpful.

Also, depending on which style you prefer you could avoid explicitly checking the count by catching the exception thrown by `Single()`.

```
try
{
    return objects.Single();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex) 
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        "%Collection% should contain one %element%, but now it's: " + objects.Count,
        ex
    );
}
```

Comment: thats the better version +1